# Ignore changes in specific files using git

Tags: git, batch-file, build

I am novice in dealing with git, but I have a repository that contains several files ending in .test
I want to know how I can check for changes made to the repository (compared to my local repo) while disregarding any changes made in these .test files.  This is part of a batch file.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the .gitignore file but when I run 
    git diff --name-only
it still shows the changes made to those test files

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.gitignore` file and commit the file:

```
#Testing files
*.[Tt]est
*_[Tt]est.*
```

Comment: will it accept regular expressions? I also have some files that are formatted like XXX_test.*

Answer (score 0):

Add a .gitignore file to the root of your project, and write this inside:

```
*.test
```

If .gitignore file already exists, just append `*.test` in the end.

Then add & commit .gitignore.

Further information: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files

Comment: will it accept regular expressions? I also have some files that are formatted like XXX_test.*

Comment: in this case you can use *test.*